# Referencing one field for two different sets of related IDs in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I'm working on a school assignment for Databases and I'm running into a lot of trouble getting this one to work.

I'm trying to make a query for two columns, one of course prerequisites and one

for course IDs. The title in both of these columns must relate to the ID it is CONCATed with, which is only located under uni_course.

Here's what my output looks like right now from the following query (and what it should look like) :

```
SELECT CONCAT(uni_course.course_id,': ',title) as Course,
       CONCAT(uni_prereq.prereq_id,': ',title) as Prerequisite
FROM uni_course
INNER JOIN uni_prereq ON uni_course.course_id = uni_prereq.course_id;
```

[image: Issue]

Any advice is very appreciated, thank you!

Comment: In case of multi-table queries, you should always use proper Aliasing, and refer the columns with their respective table alias name(s). This will prevent any ambiguous behaviour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a join on the table again to get the description of the prerequisite course, hope that will help.

```
SELECT CONCAT(c.course_id,': ',c.title) AS Course, 
       CONCAT(p.prereq_id,': ',pc.title) AS Prerequisite

FROM uni_course AS c   
INNER JOIN uni_prereq AS p ON c.course_id = p.course_id
INNER JOIN uni_course AS pc ON p.prereq_id = pc.course_id;
```

Comment: You're awesome. Thanks so much!

Comment: No problems, happy to see it helped.

Comment: @JackHappe if this answer has helped you; you should consider marking it as accepted answer. Please see: [How to accept an answer for closure](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235). Thanks :)